# fetch 404 while loading jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: nginx, caching, hosting, workbox

I have deployed my nodejs based react application to digital ocean also i have used the cloudflare for ssl and dns hosting. My project has using google workbox and lru-cache. I have made nginx settings in the digitalocean ubuntu droplet.
Everything oke except the .jpg,.jpeg product images doesnt loading browser and giving me this error

[iam showing in chrome like that](https://pasteboard.co/I4hJwKO.png)

i will solve this error but i couldnt understand interesting with what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching i concern about where is my image files in ubuntu and it has right permission to seen (chod x +R) for internet public users. Can they read my files. But i have suppresed with there is no any file in that directory. Couse ubuntu doesnt give me my process to write permisson when i uploading my jpg files with fs.sysnc

**Edited**:
After i seen that is interested with nginx settings which has looking another directory, i have corrected that and everything worked out!